# Question about Jini API

Tags: java, jini

I am trying to learn about the Jini API in java, but can't get my head around how the server and client interact, and am constantly seeing things being referred to as "smart proxies". What are smart proxies? And how does the client and server interact ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jini is based on Java RMI, so clients and servers communicate with each other just as they do in RMI: request/response using RMI protocol on the wire.

As for the "smart proxies", the Jini compiler uses a proxy factory to generate implementation code for your interface that includes an API for sending and receiving meta data about services.  This is the magic that makes it possible for a client to send out a request for a certain kind of service on the network (e.g.  "I'd like a color laser plotter") and select from the responses to find the best match possible.

Comment: So...what is this about a lease based access to servers that I keep reading about? Kind of confused about the specifics of server-client communication.

Comment: Users can send out that request for a certain kind of service; the service can send back its meta data and a time limited lease on its use.  Your question is broad - can you be more specific?  The only thing I can recommend is reading the documentation more deeply.  A quick scan won't cut it.